Tag synonym suggestions
I don't have enough reputation to suggest tag synonyms, but I've noticed these possible synonyms:
Master        <--      Synonym
word-meaning           meaning
orthography            spelling
foreign-words          borrowing 
What do you think?

Many thanks for your suggestions, Charo.
Our tags originally followed the tags on ELU, but, of course, it's necessary to check them regularly (and possibly, to clean them up). With regard to these particular tags, I'd say that

word-meaning should be left for the meaning of single words, while meaning is better suited for expressions or a combination of words (even if they don't form a proper phrase)—just as we keep two separate tage for usage and word-usage. Please feel free to correct the tags' wiki;
Orthography is not only about spelling; it includes rules of spelling, hyphenation, capitalization, word breaks, emphasis, and punctuation. Probably, it'd make sense to keep this as an "umbrella" tag along with more specific tags spelling or punctuation. It works quite well on ELU;
foreign-words is not only about borrowing (again, please feel free to correct its wiki), i.e., about words that come from another language to become part of the Italian language. It's also about words that don't belong to Italian but we use them anyway, being perfectly aware that they are NOT part of Italian. I think this question or this one get this tag just right: "FBI" for Federal Bureau of Investigation is a full English phrase, used "as is", not adapted into Italian, and another great question is about using in one name both "lago" and "Loch".


Thanks for your clarification! However, if it's that way, I think it is tag wikis that should be modified.

@randomatlabuser No problem, I've removed the suggested synonyms. Thanks for your willingness to improve these tags. Please feel free to correct the tags wiki to clarify their meaning.

By the way, I've seen that the tag "usage" has been defined as a synonym of the tag "word-usage". This fact, together with this answer, made me thought that the tag "meaning" could be defined as a synonym of the tag  "word-meaning" in an analogous way.
